# Grails 3.0.0M1 - running war standalone - no main class in MANIFEST.MF

Tags: grails, grails-3.0

Grails 3:
Trying the example from the docs to run the war file standalone:

```
$ java -Xmx768M -XX:MaxPermSize=256m -jar test-0.1.war
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: ignoring option MaxPermSize=256m; support was removed in 8.0
no main manifest attribute, in test-0.1.war
```

So which is the main class I must start?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You must use `grails package` instead of `grails war` to build a self running fatjar.